# how to install nvidia GEFORCE 720M driver on ubuntu 12.04 32-bit?

Tags: 12.10

I have an Asus laptop I try to install Nvidia drivers but I failed.

```
$ sudo service lightdm stop
$ sudo init 3
$ chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86-340.65.run
$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-340.65.run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-nvidia-driver-331-67-ubuntu1404/) it will help you.
You need to careful what you are dealing with.this **may** cause some problem to your system.

Answer (score 0):

First open terminal and navigate to the directory where your driver is.

Then enter chmod +x name-of-your-driver.run

```
       enter ./name-of-your-driver.run
```

And installer will run

**NOTE**

Please this command chmod +x name-of-your-driver.run run with sudo

Comment: try but not wrkng

Comment: this is not proper way to install